# Linking from inner batches to a section on the home page of my website

Tags: html

I have a number of sections on my homepage: About Us, Courses etc. When I try to link to a section on the homepage from inner pages like contact us I create this link:

```
<a href='http://www.example.com#courses'>Courses</a>
```

The link opens but immediately shifts to the top of the page.

How can we link to the correct section?

Comment: Does the "courses" section have a named anchor tag?

Comment: yes on the same page it is working. but when connecting from  other pages it is not working.

Comment: <a name="#courses"> on the homepage

Comment: You want `<a name="courses">...</a>` (without the `#`). But `<a id="courses">...</a>` will work the same in links, and is more standards-compliant (HTML 5 dropped support for the `name` attribute on anchors).

Comment: i inadvertently added # to the name tag. let me try with id. but the same is working on the same page but when linking from other page does not work. thanks